# Flutter adding favourite feature with SQLITE

Tags: flutter, api, sqlite

Hello flutter experts i am fetching data from Api and show in listview in my app when user click any item from listview  its saved data in sqlite now i want  if API data already  exist in sqlite then my trailing star icon change into yellow color otherwise it will remain same please check my code let me know i can achieve this type functionality  mobile app.

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
    import 'package:testfproject/Model/Articlemodel.dart';
    import 'package:testfproject/Model/Favourite/Favouritemodel.dart';
    import 'package:testfproject/Services/services.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    
    import '../Db/Databasehelper.dart';
    
    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
    
      @override
      State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
    }
    
    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
    
       // article();
      }
      Services api=Services();
      Databasehelper databasehelper=Databasehelper();
    
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('New Articles'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
         FutureBuilder(
           future: api.Article(),
           builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Articlemodel>> snapshot) {
             if(snapshot.hasData){
               List<Articlemodel>?articles=snapshot.data;
               return Expanded(
                 child: ListView.separated(
                     shrinkWrap: true,
                     itemCount:articles!.length,
                     itemBuilder: (conext,index){
                       
                       //this  list tile when user press on trailing icon it saved data in sqlite
                       return ListTile(
                         trailing: IconButton(
                         icon:Icon(Icons.star),
                           onPressed: () {
                        databasehelper.insert(Favouritemodel(author: articles[index].author.toString(), title:articles[index].title.toString()));
    
                           },
    
                         ),
    
                         title: Text(articles[index].title.toString()),
                         //subtitle: Text(articles[index].author.toString()),
                       );
                     }, separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                       return Divider();
                 },),
               );
             }else{
              return Container(
                 child: Text('NO data'),
               );
             }
    
           },
    
         )
            ],
    
          ),
        );
      }

}

//my Api services class
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:testfproject/Model/Articlemodel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class Services{
  Future<List<Articlemodel>>Article() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=0fb3a9662c3747fba42ffd3d66cc612d'));
    if(response.statusCode==200){
      var data=jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
      final Iterable json = data["articles"];
      return json.map((article) => Articlemodel.fromJson(article)).toList();

    }else{
      throw Exception('Error');

    }


  }
}


model class of api



class Articlemodel {
  Source? source;
  String? author;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  String? url;
  String? urlToImage;
  String? publishedAt;
  String? content;
  bool? iSfavourite;

  Articlemodel(
      {this.source,
        this.author,
        this.title,
        this.description,
        this.url,
        this.urlToImage,
        this.publishedAt,
        this.content,
      });

  Articlemodel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    source =
    json['source'] != null ? new Source.fromJson(json['source']) : null;
    author = json['author'];
    title = json['title'];
    description = json['description'];
    url = json['url'];
    urlToImage = json['urlToImage'];
    publishedAt = json['publishedAt'];
    content = json['content'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.source != null) {
      data['source'] = this.source!.toJson();
    }
    data['author'] = this.author;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['urlToImage'] = this.urlToImage;
    data['publishedAt'] = this.publishedAt;
    data['content'] = this.content;
    return data;
  }
}

class Source {
  String? id;
  String? name;

  Source({this.id, this.name});

  Source.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
  }
//model class of sqlite for favouriting


class Favouritemodel {Favouritemodel(

    {required  this.author,required  this.title,}

    );

  Favouritemodel.fromJson(dynamic json) {

    author = json['author'];
    title = json['title'];

  }

  String? author;
  String? title;


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};

    map['author'] = author;
    map['title'] = title;

    return map;
  }

}
//database helper class

import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import '../Model/Favourite/Favouritemodel.dart';

class Databasehelper{
  static Database? _db;
   bool check=false;


  Future<Database?> get db async {
    if(_db != null)
      return _db;
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
  }

  //Creating a database with name test.dn in your directory
  initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "favourite.db");
    var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return theDb;
  }

  // Creating a table
  void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    // When creating the db, create the table
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE favourite(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, author TEXT, title  TEXT  unique )");
    print("Created tables");
  }
  //insert data
  Future<Favouritemodel> insert(Favouritemodel favouritemodel) async {

    Database? db = await this.db;
    await db!.insert('favourite', favouritemodel.toJson()).catchError((e)=>(debugPrint(e)));

   return favouritemodel;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

first add this function to your database helper

```
Future<List<Favouritemodel>> favourites() async {
  Database? db = await this.db;

  final List<Map> data = await db!.query('favourite');

  return data.map((e) => Favouritemodel.fromJson(e)).toList();
}
```

and override the equal operator in `Favouritemodel`

```
@override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return identical(this, other) ||
        (other is Favouritemodel &&
            author == other.author &&
            title == other.title);
```

receive the favourite list in the build method:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final futureFavourites = databasehelper.favourites();
  return Scaffold(
    // ...
```

and finally change the itemBuilder to this:

```
itemBuilder: (conext, index) {
  return FutureBuilder<List<Favouritemodel>>(
    future: futureFavourites,
    builder: (context, favouriteSnapshot) {
      if(!favouriteSnapshot.hasData) {
        return ListTile(title: Text('Loading...'));
      }
      final favourites = favouriteSnapshot.data!;
      final favouriteModel = Favouritemodel(author: articles[index].author.toString(),
                               title:articles[index].title.toString());
      
      final isFavourite = favourites.contains(favouriteModel);
      return ListTile(
        trailing: IconButton(
          icon:Icon(Icons.star, color: isFavourite ? Colors.yellow : null),
          onPressed: () {
              databasehelper.insert(favouriteModel);
          },
        ),
        title: Text(articles[index].title.toString()),
        //subtitle: Text(articles[index].author.toString()),
      );
    }
  );
}
```